# Taking out an animated element of one website and pasting into another.

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am moderizing a friends website.

The existing website is "www.ecoclean.cl" and the new one I am doing is "www.ecoclean.cl/paul"

Now, on his existing website there is an animation of a truck passing houses (you can see it in the footer of each page).

I have tried copy/pasting the images and css part of the website into the new one and it simply doesn't work... I just get a huge truck png there, no houses... no animation.

From what I can see, there are 3 elements being used.  a js, a CSS, and of course the images.

I simply want to take the existing animation, and place it onto the new website I am making.

** You know.  Today isn't my day.  suddenly every time I try to post HTML or any code in here the thing doesn't work.  Sorry.

If anyone can help, or maybe go to the page and try to figure it out, I would be eternally grateful, I've tried various ways and none seems to work.

:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you didn't already try that - you also have to the use this file: http://www.ecoclean.cl/funciones.js. There you'll find on top the `function camion() {}` that is called in the page in inline javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    camion(); camion2();
    s=setInterval("slide2()",3000);     
});
```

and include the truck-image with the id that is used in this function (`cam`) as it's used in the current HTML:

```
<figure id="cam">
      <img src="media/footer/camion.png">
 </figure>
```

I've just added this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gge3bhyo/) where you can see the truck moving from left to right. I've only added the funciones.js and the part from above $(document).ready() function as well as some CSS to set the truck to the size it's displayed on the site.

**Update** for the comments: I've just added a 2nd [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9j2b7b3/) with the houses added. To add code, you can either have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for the information that you get when you click first the question mark on the right side in edit mode and then "advanced help".
In short - you can either paste code, then select/highlight the code and click the 5th icon in the toolbar, or start pasting your code after you enter 4 spaces. Just try it out, you'll see the result in the preview below the edit window.
As you have some detail questions: first, the houses. The houses are displayed as background image for the `footer`. Just check how it's done in the 2nd Fiddle. If you already use the CSS from the orignal site, maybe the image is missing or not at the correct location, but maybe you just have to add the `footer` element and the houses image will be displayed.

**Update** for the issue with the image of the buildings: In the original CSS the background-image is referenced relative:  `background-image: url("media/footer/fondo.png");`. Having http://www.ecoclean.cl/ as root, the image is located in this folder: http://www.ecoclean.cl/media/footer/fondo.png In the Fiddle I've just used the absolute URL - http://www.ecoclean.cl/media/footer/fondo.png - for the background image as well as for the truck as otherwise the Fiddle couldn't display the images. In your previous test you've just added a wrong absolute URL - http://www.ecoclean.cl/paul/media/footer/fondo.png - so you could either adjust the URL (better to the relative version) or create the directory `media` in the directory `paul`, the directory `footer` in this `media` directory and copy the image there.
And as sidenote for the jquery - I've just pasted above all three function calls (`camion()`, `camion2()` and the `slide2()` with the timeout ) as found on the current page, but for the truck only the camions are used. The `slide()` call may cause an error in case you wouldn't also add the slider in the HTML with the id `slide_largo`.

Comment: Thank you... and how did you copy/paste code in here.. I tried 4 times and it didn't let me.  I am going to inject the code in the new website... give me a moment.

Comment: Ok, so I added the html code into the new page... no problems there.  Now, I just put the WHOLE js file into the new website... and it isn't working.  :(

Comment: @PaulUrmston Don't worry. Is it possible that you haven't included jquery before including the functiones.js (or the content of this)..? And just in case you added the whole js from this file - did you wrap it in `<script>` - tags?

Comment: Ok, I uploaded the js, CSS, and updated the new index.  It's at www.ecoclean.cl/paul  You can see the truck... but no buildings or animation... so I'm like 50% there lol!  Very frustrating.  I've never done animations like this, I'm just trying to rescue the element for my friend.

Comment: So as I said.  I now have a "truck.css" added into the new site.  And WHY can I not post code directly in here?

Comment: Hey... didn't see the fiddle.  Man, you are GOOD!  How do I get the houses (can be seen on original website) in there too?

Comment: I uploaded the original css, js, and aded the HTML into my page... I get a truck, but no houses or movement... so something is broken somewhere.  :(

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Ok, so I can see it working in the 2nd fiddle.  I copy/paste the code as is... and still I get no buildings.  There was also a clash with this "footer" form the old website, and the new "footer" of mine.  I changed all the code from the old footer to footer2... and still I have the truck, but no buildings.  Weird.  Don't think I am going to be able to get this one at all.  But again, thank you so much!!!

Comment: @PaulUrmston Don't mind, glad if I can be of help. The image of the buildings is just a minor issue. I've just checked your updated site and noticed that the image was missing as the server was down, but you should try as follows: change the path to the image as I only added the full URL in the fiddle because otherwise it wouldn't work in the fiddle. In the original site the image is referenced relative (no full URL), also in your current CSS the url is wrong - http://www.ecoclean.cl/paul/media/footer/camion.png instead of http://www.ecoclean.cl/media/footer/camion.png